# How to Pass a Route Parameter to a Property on my Controller with WebApi?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Suppose I have a route like the following:

/api/v1/{organisationId}/resource/{resourceId}

Since there are likely to be a number of different types of resources hanging off an organisation, I'd like a common way of dealing with the organisationId.

What I thought of doing is creating a base controller (inheriting from ApiController, obviously) which would have an OrganisationId property.

Is there any way to get WebApi to pass the organisationId route parameter to a property on the controller, rather than to a parameter on the action method?

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
public int OrganisationId
{
    get
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(Request.GetRouteData().Values["organisationId"]);
    }
}
```

This is not using the model binding layer and is assuming that `organisationId` would be present in the route data. It is simple and a bit less flexible than what web API model binding offers.

Answer (score 1):

The downside to reading the route from within the property getter is unit testing could be a challenge. Another possible approach is to explore implementing your own IHttpControllerActivator that sets the OrganizationId property. Yes, for this to work, you will need a base controller or the property defined in the individual controllers, when not derived from the base. If you go with base, you can cast IHttpController type to the base and set the property. Or you can resort to reflection.